# Generic object in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, object

I'm new with C#. In vb.net I can have a list of object and I can add the new one with the next lines:

```
Dim lObject = new list (of object)
lObject.add(new with{.id = 1, .name ="hello"})
```

After that I can access every row of list and every field.

Any idea how can I do that in C#? Without create a specific class

Thanxs

Comment: _"After that I can access every row of list and every field"_ -- please be more specific. The literal C# equivalent to the code you posted is `lObject.Add(new { Id = 1, Name = "hello" })`, but in C# you won't be able to access the properties of that anonymous type. In VB.NET, it is possible to access the properties even from the `Object` type, but it would be better if in your question you are clear about how you are doing so.

Comment: That code uses an anonymous type via a type initialiser.  The very same thing can be done in C#, simply with a slightly different syntax.  If you search for those keywords in conjunction with C#, you'll find the information you want.  That said, it's not ideal that you are creating a `List(Of Object)` in the first place.  Instead, if possible, you should create a `List` of that specific type with type inference, i.e. `Dim myList = {New With {.Id = 1, .Name = "Hello"}}.ToList()`.

Answer (score 4):

In c#? You could cheat with value-tuples:

```cs
var list = new List<(int id, string name)>();
list.Add((1, "hello"));
```

(Although technically these aren't objects until boxed, but: it'll do the job)

In reality: just declare the class that you clearly want here. It'll save you a lot of pain:

```cs
class Something {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and use a `List<Something>`

Comment: This answer does not provide C# equivalent to the VB code that was posted.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: it's true that it doesn't. But, it won't be possible to provide a literal exact match, because C# won't do the dynamic binding that VB.NET does. I.e. in VB.NET it's legal to add an anonymous object to the list, then retrieve that object later and still get at the properties without knowing the type. C# only offers that through the `dynamic` type, not `object`. Given the vague question, the above seems like a reasonable C# alternative, and IMHO is structurally superior in any case.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Is that because of `Option Strict` being off?  Or will it still work with `Option Strict` on?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: VB.NET only does late-binding with `Option Strict Off`. There are ways to do it explicitly with `Option Strict On`, but they are not IMHO worth bothering with. I'm not sure I'd say it's _because_ of `Option Strict Off`. VB.NET could have been implemented without late-binding at all. But that's the only mode in which the feature is active. In any case, the code the OP posted would only work when late-binding is enabled, so we can safely assume that's the context in which they expect an answer.